# getting errors in php coding something undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting following error in this code : `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 12
Success`

also other error are `Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 101`

`Notice: Undefined variable: fulltarget in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 101`

Here is the pastebin link to see the whole code : http://pastebin.com/JKegmNHC

Also here is the code also available.. you can see it through here or using the pastebin link to get the error indication right from the related line....

Here is the code :

```
    <?php

$submit=$_POST['sub'];
if(isset($submit))
{
$name=$_FILES['img']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['img']['type'];

$size=($_FILES['img']['size'])/1024;

$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
if (($ext == "gif")
|| ($ext == "jpeg")
|| ($ext == "jpg")
|| ($ext =="png")
&& ($size > 30))
{


############################## File Renaming ###################################################

$newname=uniqid();
//$ext=end(explode('.',$name));
$fullname=$newname.".".$ext;
$target="pics/";
$fulltarget=$target.$fullname;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$fulltarget))
{
echo "Success";
}
else
{
echo "Failed";
}
############################## File Renaming end ###################################################
}
else{
echo "not successful";
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abhi.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Php Image Uploader</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="a1">
<form name="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Store" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="a2">

<?php echo "
<html>
<head>
<title>Aviary Photo Editer</title>
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js'></script>
<!-- Instantiate Feather -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
apiKey: 'ceegvx4siylhayrr',
apiVersion: 3,
theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
tools: 'enhance,frames,crop,orientation,brightness,saturation,sharpness,draw,redeye,blemish,effects,stickers,resize,focus,contrast,warmth,colorsplash,text,whiten',
appendTo: '',
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    img.src = newURL;
},
onError: function(errorObj) {
    alert(errorObj.message);
}
});
function launchEditor(id, src) {
featherEditor.launch({
    image: id,
    url: src
 });
return false;
}
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='$fulltarget'/>

<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick=\"return launchEditor('image1', '$fulltarget');\" /></p>";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [[PHP: end - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)], when you use `end()` it passes the last element in the array as a *reference*.

You can try a couple things:

1. Don't use `explode()` in `end()`. Try doing the explode when you declare `$name`:
   `$name = explode( '.', $_FILES['img']['name'] );`
2. Use `array_slice()` and `list()` instead of `end()`:
   `list($ext) = array_slice( explode( '.' , $name ), -1 );`

Either one would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

You get 'Notice: Undefined variable' errors because you try to use a variable without initializing it first. In your HTML you use '$fulltarget', but it's only set after you submitted the form. If you want to get rid of this notice you should put something like `$fulltarget = '';` after your PHP opening tag.

If you will check the PHP `end()` function documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php you will see that the function takes an array as a parameter through reference. To fix this error you should save your `explode()` results as a variable and then pass that variable to `end()` function. For example: `$arr = explode('.', $name); $ext = end($arr);`

Comment: what about this error please it happens when i upload picture and the picture get shown so it displays...`Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploader\upload.php on line 12 Success`

Comment: The second paragraph of my answer explains what is the problem with this error.